# How to convert a string to lower case using bash 3.1 available in gitExtension

Tags: bash, git

I'm writing a pre-rebase hook for Git using bash script and I need to convert a string to lowerCase or UperCase. I tried some methods doumented in [Bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

*example:*

```
 myString="AbcDFmk";
 echo ${myString,,}
```

and this is the result: `${myString,}: bad substitution`

Can you please help me to find a way to do this?

Comment: Works here (Ubuntu 14.04, GNU bash, Version 4.3.11(1) ) - what's your bash version?

Comment: Use `tr`. Example `$ echo "Hello World" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) you mention is for Bash version 4.3. String substitutions are not supported in 3.1.

You can use *tr* like this:

```
echo $(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'<<<${myString})
```